# Changing user name leaves orphaned comment references

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, comments, display-names

On [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5583608/difference-between-res-and-assets-directories/5583782#5583782), I left a comment in response to another comment. When I posted the response, the other comment's author had a display name of "vwvwvwvwvwvwvwvwvw" and I started my comment with "@vwvwvwvwvwvwvwvwvw". Since then, the other display name has changed to "Vivek Warde". Now my comment has a stale (nonsensical-looking) reference to a non-existent user name. My comment is long past the age for editing, so there isn't much I can do about it.

In this particular case, it's obvious to whom I'm responding, but in longer comment threads, an orphaned user reference might be very confusing for someone trying to read through the comments. After all, it's conceivable that over time two users in the same comment thread might even exchange display names!

Would it be possible to enhance SO so that when a user changes his or her display name, all comments that have links to that name are automatically edited so that the name references track the name change?

Comment: I have felt the confusion of this myself a few times. At the same time, I can see this being low priority since comments are second-class citizens around here... But I would hope this can be done at some point!

Comment: Related: [Change all @username references in comments when a user changes their name?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/31851/change-all-username-references-in-comments-when-a-user-changes-their-name)

Comment: It would probably be horribly expensive, since username tags in comments are just plain text and aren't linked to a specific account. There could also be ambiguity if a second person by the same name got involved in a conversation, and then one changed their name.

Comment: Yeah, unclosable dupe that's now on meta.se.

Comment: @AndrewMedico - Somehow the engine can parse and disambiguate such references when comments are entered, since targets get notified of responses in their inboxes. Perhaps it would be very expensive to apply this retroactively, but since the parsing is going on anyway, I don't see how it would be such a huge deal if the parse results were captured and used for comment maintenance.

Comment: Just for reference [how comment replies work](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/43020/158100)

Comment: The post that @rene references also has a very highly-rated comment asking for this behavior -- Since we're already doing the calculation to decide what user it is, go ahead and encode that decision into an unambiguous userID notation

Comment: If we can have some statistics on how many users changes their displayname per day/week/month we get an idea how big this problem really is... my bet is: it is a relative minor annoyance with a lot of potential to waste many dev hours on it...

Comment: @AndrewMedico: Doing this effectively would basically require adding one field to the Comments table, containing the user ID of the @-notified user (or NULL). Then, when a user changes their name, fetch a list of old comments notifying the user and schedule a background job to update them. (I'd also consider adding another field for the offset of the relevant @ in the comment, or somehow mangling the comment text to make sure I can always unambiguously identify the correct username to change, even if the comment has many @ signs and/or the user has previously chosen an ambiguous name.)

Comment: To be honest, SE needs to totally ovrerhaul the comments system, it needs rebuilding from the ground up

Comment: It's also possible to delete a comment entirely, which can then leave a similarly orphaned reference in a following comment to a user name for which there are no comments, but it would be entirely non-obvious to the casual reader why or how that happened, and since the context of the comment itself is lost then the following comment is left potentially stranded.

Comment: @ClickRick - Yes, and that's exactly what my comment in the post I referenced looks like, until you read the substance of the two comments and realize that they are a coherent conversation. If comments had a structure in which user references had semantic value, the system could even use special highlighting to distinguish references to ex-participants. It wouldn't cover all cases, but would improve the usability of the comment system.

Comment: Not really on point, but the principle of this problem is the reason I reference other users in non @username situations, by `[<username>](http://<SE site>.com/users/<userid>)`

Comment: why not set-up the system to pull a <user_id> not set by the user and unchangeable and use that to pull the <user_name> which is set by the user and can be changed to prevent the possibility of orphaned comment references.

Comment: I think I have better idea: Make tree out of the comment section. Every reply, is growing out of the reply's target.

Comment: My display name used to be my full name, but I have since removed by first name for privacy (Google searches by prospective employers etc.). It still shows up in comments i.e. to this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/2636628/832052. I'd rather not delete the comment but it seems I have no choice. This is a flaw in the system.

Comment: *Now my comment has a stale (nonsensical-looking) reference to a non-existent user name* - this also occurs (if not worse) if someone deletes their comment so your @whomever is a reply to nothing.

Comment: @achAmháin - At least in that case someone might guess what happened. When someone changes their name, the stale reference looks exactly the same. It would be helpful if these situations could be distinguished.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, I'm pretty sure they can. The only thing (or things) the admins need to do is include this 'hidden tag' with every user that also points to the current username; the name to display. That ways you can change your username, but because you can't change the hidden tag, it's automatically going to change. The comments will automatically update with every update of the tag, so it's going to keep up.

Not that I can, but I think ^^that^^ will work.

Comment: This was [status-declined](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/270105/revisions) 11 days ago by [animuson♦](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/246246/animuson).  Sorry. I kind of like the idea too, but I imagine that with the ridiculous number of users that there's a lot of name changes happening, and this would add significant computational overhead for comments, which are supposed to be transient anyway.

Comment: This is why I think that the username references should be converted to the userid, instead of the username at the database level.. we already do this for URLs, so why not for @username combinations?